# sys.getrefcount() returning very large reference counts

Tags: python, cpython, python-3.11

In CPython 3.11, the following code returns very large reference counts for some objects.  It seems to follow pre-cached objects like integers -5 to 256, but CPython 3.10 does not:

```py
Python 3.11.2 (tags/v3.11.2:878ead1, Feb  7 2023, 16:38:35) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for i in (-6, -5, 0, 255, 256, 257):
...    print(i, sys.getrefcount(i))
...
-6 5
-5 1000000004
0 1000000535
255 1000000010
256 1000000040
257 5
```

```py
Python 3.10.8 (tags/v3.10.8:aaaf517, Oct 11 2022, 16:50:30) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for i in (-6, -5, 0, 255, 256, 257):
...    print(i, sys.getrefcount(i))
...
-6 5
-5 6
0 234
255 8
256 26
257 5
```

[PEP 683 - Immortal Objects, Using a Fixed Refcount](https://peps.python.org/pep-0683/) may be related, but it isn't mentioned in [What's New in Python 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html), nor is a change in `sys.getrefcount()` documented.

Anybody have knowledge about this change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *not* related to PEP 683, but it will probably be superseded by PEP 683 once PEP 683 has been implemented.

This refcount change was first introduced in a [commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/121f1f893a39d0b58d3d2b5597505c154ecaac2a) on December 13, 2021, which introduced a `_PyObject_IMMORTAL_INIT` macro:

```
#define _PyObject_IMMORTAL_INIT(type) \
    { \
        .ob_refcnt = 999999999, \
        .ob_type = type, \
    }
```

Before this change, small int refcounts were initialized to 1. This change made it so their refcounts were instead initialized to 999999999.

The relevant issue discussion is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90111), and the pull request for the commit is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/30092).

The value of 999999999 seems to have been copied from a fairly arbitrary decision Guido van Rossum made while writing an unrelated tool. Quoting a [message](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90111#issuecomment-1093939287) by Guido in the issue discussion:

> I used 999999999 in deepfreeze.py to signify "immortal object". It has
> been copied by others (small integers are essentially immortal too). I
> wasn't too sure that the refcount wouldn't go below zero if the
> interpreter is repeatedly finalized and reinitialized. Once we have
> official immortal objects (see PEP-683) we should switch to that.